# Zero-inflated negative binomial non-integer error

Tags: r, winbugs

I am fitting ZINB in WinBugs using `R2Winbug` and this is WinBugs model code:

```
Model{
  for(i in 1:n){
    injections[i] ~ dnegbin(p[i],r)
    p[i] <- r/r+ramda[i]*(1-u[i])
    u[i] ~ dbern(p0[i])
    logit(p0[i])  <- alpha0 + alpha1*hiv[i] + alpha2*parteners[i] + 
                     alpha3*married[i] + alpha4*divorced[i] + alpha5*mage[i]
    log(ramda[i]) <- beta0 + beta1*hiv[i] + beta2*parteners[i] + 
                     beta3*married[i] + beta4*divorced[i] + beta5*mage[i]
  }
  # priors for missing covariates
  for(i in 1:n){
    parteners[i] ~ dpois(mu)
    hiv[i] ~ dbin(q,1)
  }

  # priors
  q ~ dunif(0.0,1.0)
  r <- exp(logalpha)
  logalpha ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8)
  beta0 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8); beta1 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8) 
  beta2 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8); beta3 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8)
  beta4 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8); beta5 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8) 
  alpha0 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8); alpha1 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8); alpha2 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8)
  alpha3 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8); alpha4 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8); alpha5 ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-8)
  mu ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
}
```

Now after calling the bugs function, the model is said to be correct, data is also loaded correctly, but when initials are given, it says value of binomial hiv[16] must be an integer! How can I correct this problem?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Well, the binomial family does expect values that are .... binomial. It would appear this is a question that should have been directed first to the package maintainer and only after that failed, to some other forum.